# Error: TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was writing a program to construct a GAN in which generator class takes in a tf module with all initialization required, but when this class is initialized and finally called, i am facing an error of extra arguments being passed (complete error i have posted below)

```
    class Generator(tf.Module):
        def __init__(self, noise_size, condition_size, generator_latent_size, cell_type, mean=0, std=1):
            super().__init__()
    
            self.noise_size = noise_size
            self.condition_size = condition_size
            self.generator_latent_size = generator_latent_size
            self.mean = mean
            self.std = std
    
            if cell_type == "lstm":
                self.cond_to_latent = tf.keras.layers.LSTM(generator_latent_size)
            else:
                self.cond_to_latent = tf.keras.layers.GRU(generator_latent_size)
    
            self.model = tf.keras.Sequential(
                tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=((generator_latent_size + self.noise_size),)),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(generator_latent_size + self.noise_size),
                tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
                tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
    
            )
    
        def forward(self, noise, condition):
            condition = (condition - self.mean) / self.std
            condition = condition.view(-1, self.condition_size, 1)
            condition = condition.transpose(0, 1)
            condition_latent, _ = self.cond_to_latent(condition)
            condition_latent = condition_latent[-1]
            g_input = tf.concat((condition_latent, noise), dim=1)
            output = self.model(g_input)
            output = output * self.std + self.mean
    
            return output
    
        def get_noise_size(self):
            return self.noise_size
```

when is generator object is called, i am getting an error in internal method wrapper stating

```
" Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "forgan.py", line 185, in <module>
    forgan = ForGAN(opt)
  File "forgan.py", line 35, in __init__
    std=opt.data_std)
  File "C:\Users\mura_ab\PycharmProjects\ForGAN\components.py", line 23, in __init__
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
  File "C:\Users\mura_ab\Anaconda3\envs\Plygrnd\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\training\tracking\base.py", line 457, in _method_wrapper
    result = method(self, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: __init__() takes from 1 to 3 positional arguments but 5 were given"
```

this is the Generator object being initilized:

```
    class ForGAN:
        def __init__(self, opt):
            self.opt = opt
            self.device = tf.device("cuda:0") if tf.test.is_gpu_available() else tf.device("cpu")
            print("*****  Hyper-parameters  *****")
            for k, v in vars(opt).items():
                print("{}:\t{}".format(k, v))
            print("************************")
    
            # Making required directories for logging, plots and models' checkpoints
            os.makedirs("./{}/".format(self.opt.dataset), exist_ok=True)
    
            # Defining GAN components
            self.generator = Generator(noise_size=opt.noise_size,
                                       condition_size=opt.condition_size,
                                       generator_latent_size=opt.generator_latent_size,
                                       cell_type=opt.cell_type,
                                       mean=opt.data_mean,
                                       std=opt.data_std)
```

and at last called by

```
forgan = ForGAN(opt)
```

Can someone please let me know if there is any workaround method to tackle this problem.

Comment: can you post the entire error and the code generating it?

Comment: Hi, I have posted the entire error and part of code which is generating it

Comment: @AbhishekM I dont see the line 35 (mentioned in the error)

Comment: `Sequential` takes a _list_ of layers.

Comment: I had the same error. You should set contents of `Sequential` function into square brackets `tf.keras.Sequential([...])`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you should pay close attention to what the error message says. Instead of answering to solve your error straight away, I'm gonna show you how I found it in hopes you'll do it on your own with the next error you get.

Reading all the info of the error one by one:

1. We know the error appears in the creation of your forgan.

```
File "forgan.py", line 185, in <module>
    forgan = ForGAN(opt)
```

2. More concretely, we know it has something to do with the initialization of the Generator,

```
line 35, in __init__
    std=opt.data_std)
```

3. It seems to be related with an initialization in line 23, which could come from the creation of a Dense layer (or something below the Dense layer), or with the initialization of the Sequential model (after all, line 23 is part of the initialization of the sequential model happening in line 19):

```
  File "C:\Users\mura_ab\PycharmProjects\ForGAN\components.py", line 23, in __init__
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
```

4. The error goes out of your code.

It is clear by the text in the error that you used 5 arguments to initialize an object somewhere. Seeing step 3, you didn't initialize the Dense layer using 5 arguments. However, you seem to be initializing the Sequential model with 4 arguments... and if you add the hidden `self` argument always present in Python object initializations, it adds up to **5 arguments**! Maybe you're doing something wrong when initializing the Sequential model.

To corroborate it, you should take a look at the official API or some other official guide. Googling it, you can easily get to [this API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/Sequential) and [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras/sequential_model). In the API you can see that the initialization requires between no extra arguments and 2 extra arguments(1 to 3 including the `self`). That's exactly what your error says! In the guide you can see examples on how to use it properly. It looks like the layers should be passed inside a container (list or tuple).

Therefore, this should solve the issue (notice the extra square brackets to turn all 5 arguments into a single list):

```
        self.model = tf.keras.Sequential([
            tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=((generator_latent_size + self.noise_size),)),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(generator_latent_size + self.noise_size),
            tf.keras.layers.ReLU(),
            tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)

        ])
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explaination, it solved the problem.